# SQL Dump of full tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I wish to make an SQL Dump of all the tables of my database
to get all the full tables, I used the following query :

```
show full tables where Table_Type != 'VIEW';
```

The output was a list of tables and the table type.
Now I want to use the result of the above query to take the dump
Let's say Database Name -> myDBName
Here is what I tried ->

```
mysqldump -uUserName -pPassword myDBName --ignore-table where 
Table_Type='VIEW' > dumpfileName.sql
```

But this did not work. Here is the error that I got
Illegal use of option --ignore-table=.

What should be the correct mysqldump command to get a dump of all full tables, i.e. tables which are not views

Comment: "-- is for comments in sql ( --ignore-table where )" could you try

 mysqldump -uUserName -pPassword myDBName where Table_Type != 'VIEW' > dumpfileName.sql

Comment: It does not work. This is the error - Couldn't find table: "where"